# How to print contents of mongoengine's QuerySet

Tags: python, mongoengine

I want to print QuerySet for debugging purposes. It's constructed dynamically like this:

```
qs = self.model.objects
orm_lookups = [self.construct_search(str(search_field)) for search_field in self.search_fields]
for bit in search_query.split():
    or_queries = [Q(**{orm_lookup: bit}) for orm_lookup in orm_lookups]
    qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
```

There is a method named `to_json` but unfortunately it returns empty list. Is there any way to get readable equivalent of the query set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as_pymongo().

That will give you a list of dictionaries that you can print.

```
qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries)).as_pymongo()
print qs
```

Just one other pointer you should look into is that maybe your query is not actually returning any results if to_json() is returning an empty dictionary.

Comment: That's exactly the reason I wanted to debug my query. Since it's constructed programmatically it's somewhat hard to imagine the result in query.